# Trying to parse JSON in Xcode NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: php, ios, json

I've been parsing JSON in Xcode like so:

```
-(void)getCheckUserData:(NSData *)data {

NSError *error;
if (!error) {

checkUserJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Uh Oh" message:@"Spaghetti-O" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}


}

-(void) startCheckingUserLogin {

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kCheck_user]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:20.0];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
                                                               delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kCheck_user];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self getCheckUserData:data];
}  

}
```

But I hired a web developer and he updated my outdated php files that took data from phpmyadmin and encoded it in JSON. Now I get an NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 message in xcode.

Here is the php file I grab the data from:

```
 <?php 

 require_once( 'classes/secure.php' );
 $SECURE = new Secure();

 if( !isset( $_POST[ 'var1' ] ) ) { exit("ERROR: no var1"); }
 if( !isset( $_POST[ 'var2' ] ) ) { exit("ERROR: no var2"); }

 $VARONE = $_POST[ 'var1' ];
 $VARTWO  = $_POST[ 'var2' ];

 $RESULT = $SECURE->checkPassword( $VARONE, $VARTWO ); // Check VARONE / VARTWO
 unset( $SECURE ); // Unset Secure
 exit( json_encode( $RESULT ) ); // Return result as JSON string

 ?>
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Can you perform the request to the web service manually (ie not through the app) and edit your post to include the result? In other words are you sure your json is legit?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the encoding.  I had one web service that worked fine 99% of the time but one response to one endpoint with certain parameters failed.  I ran the request in RESTClient and noticed in the header that the response is ISO-8859-1, aka Latin-1.

The trick is to convert the Latin-1 data into an NSString, then use the NSString to convert back to UTF8 data to make NSJSONSerialization happy.

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self->receivedData options:0 error:&error];
if (!json && error && [error.domain isEqualToString:NSCocoaErrorDomain] && (error.code == NSPropertyListReadCorruptError)) {
    // Encoding issue, try Latin-1
   NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self->receivedData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
   if (jsonString) {
        // Need to re-encode as UTF8 to parse, thanks Apple
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]
            options:0 error:&error];
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are pleny of great REST tools out there, you might want to check some of them out.  RESTClient is a plugin for Firefox.

Comment: Just saying: If the server sends what is supposed to be JSON in ISO-8859-1, then it isn't valid JSON, and the server is broken. JSON is UTF-8, or UTF-16, or UTF-32. Nothing else.